# Proving that $Pr(X\ge m/2) \ge 1/(m+1)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$, a discrete random variable of an unknown distribution above $\{0,\ldots, m\}$. It's given that $\mathbb E[X] = \frac{m}{2}$. Prove that $Pr(X\ge m/2) \ge \frac{1}{m+1}$

So I tried to prove it by contradiction. Let's assume that $Pr(X\ge m/2) < \frac{1}{m+1}$. Then:

$$\frac{m}{2} = \mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[X | X<m/2] \cdot Pr(X<m/2) + 
\mathbb E[X | X\ge m/2] \cdot Pr(X\ge m/2)  \\
<\frac{m}{2} \cdot Pr(X<m/2)+\frac{m}{m+1}$$

but this only leads to the following:

$$P(X\ge m/2) < \frac{2}{m+1}$$

No contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second equality is wrong. In fact, $$\begin{split}\frac{m}{2} = \sum_{k=0}^mk\cdot p(X=k) &\leq \frac{m-1}{2}\cdot p\left(X<\frac{m}{2}\right) + m\cdot p\left(X\geq\frac{m}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{m-1}{2}+\frac{m+1}{2}\cdot p\left(X\geq\frac{m}{2}\right)\end{split}$$
which implies $$p\left(X\geq\frac{m}{2}\right)\geq\frac{1}{m+1}$$ as desired. This proof follows a similar approach to proving Chebyshev's Inequality.

Comment: thank you. could you explain the second equality? (where did the $P(X < m/2)$ go)?

Comment: I substituted $P\left(X<\frac{m}{2}\right)$ with $1-P\left(X\geq\frac{m}{2}\right)$ (since they add up to $1$)

Comment: Oh of course. Thanks again!